# useSelector hook in Reactjs not working causing a $RefreshSig$ is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-applications, useselector

I am having trouble finding the cause of this error. I have seen it before but I am unable to fix this one. The browser shows a **$RefreshSig$ is not a function**. I don't believe it has anything to do with react and react-refresh versions because I already checked that and saw this before and fixed it by moving the useSelector outside of a function. This case is different as I would not know where to move the useSelector. The commented code: **//const selectedValue...** is the old code and I am trying to replace it with the useSelector hook. Here is the code screenshots:

[image]

Browser error:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!